# How can I duplicate a bay with its coastline and close the Polygon with a straight line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am novice in QGIS and I am trying to find a way to copy/cut/clip a polygon(coastline) to a new shape and new layer and close the polygon with a straight line. The new shape should contain at least the georeference and the calculated area of the lot.

In other words I have to enclose a bay in a new shape but close the bay mouth with a straight line as a new shape(restricted fishing area). This has to be repeated in many geographic areas. With CYAN color is the land and with WHITE is the sea. The RED is the enclosed area banned from fishing.

[image]

Comment: Land in Cyan and water in white is contraintuitive. You should stick to conventions, at least for the sake of asking a question to make it better understandable. It's confusing otherwise.

Comment: I know I am sorry about that but the file was extracted for Arcgis as a photo.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new layer
2. Start editing, enable snapping and trace
3. Draw the bay following the shoreline

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools`, you have at least two (very similar) options:

### `Union` tool (no auxiliary layer necessary):

1. Draw a polygon overlapping the area you want to copy on the same layer.
2. Run the `Union` tool
3. Select the polygons that do not represent the overlapping and delete them

*Output of `Union` tool with red outline: delete no. 1 and 2:*
[image]

### `Clip` tool (auxiliary layer necessary)

1. Draw a polygon overlapping the area you want to copy on a new, auxiliary layer (`poly2` on the screenshot).
2. Run the `Clip` tool with the two layers as input.

*Red: output of the `Clip` tool*
[image]

Comment: Thanks brother, I will try it.