# Capturing accurate polygons from field data

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, line, tracklog

Drawing out a new polygon with snapping enabled to closely follow the vertices of the track line that I have seems to work, but I get the impression that the track itself has far more information that is not being encoded in the polygon, i.e., I believe the polygon formed in this way is not sufficiently high resolution.

How do I make sure that all of the GPS points that make up the track are directly used to make the vertices of the overlay polygon?

Comment: Connecting the points in their order, e.g. using Menu processing > Toolbox > Points to path

Comment: Use Trace: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419746/how-can-i-duplicate-a-bay-with-its-coastline-and-close-the-polygon-with-a-straig/419753#419753